# Youtube URL autocorrecting to "youtube.com___" in search bar

Tags: google-chrome, search, youtube

In the search bar in Chrome, when I start to type youtube, it will automatically give me youtube.com___ first. The first suggestion will be "youtube.com___/", and then "youtube.com__/", then "youtube.com_/", and then all the way at the bottom, "https://youtube.com".

It *only* happens with youtube, no other website does this.

It's *very* annoying as it basically makes it extremely hard to navigate to youtube, especially when trying to search it.

Here is a picture showing the problem,

[image: Picture of the problem]

This has been happening to me for years, but I haven't bothered asking why until now. I recently switched from Safari back to Chrome, as it feels more responsive, but I'm facing the dreaded youtube problem again. I can't find any other information about this on the internet.

I'm running Chrome 39.0.2171.7 dev (64-bit) on Mac OS X Yosemite Public Beta 5

EDIT: I have gone through the search engines in "Manage Search Engines" in chrome://settings. I found that a lot of websites have duplicated domains with an underscore, like "deviantart.com_" for example. I tested this by seeing if this problem happened with deviantart, or any of the other websites like this, but no, it only happens with Youtube. Youtube also had a search engine for each underscored version. I deleted all of these, but unfortunately nothing happened, the problem still remained after restarting Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could possibly be a in your history, so auto-completing
Clear your history by:

1) Click the 3-horizontal-lines icon Google Chrome Settings icon in the top-right corner of the window and select Settings.

2) In the Settings window, click the Show advanced settings link.

3) In the Privacy section, click the Clear browsing data button.

4) In the Clear browsing data window, choose the duration of time to clear browsing data for (the past hour, the past week, etc.) and select the items you want to delete.

5) Click the Clear browsing data button to delete the selected browsing data.

Comment: This worked thanks, I don't know why I didn't try this, annoying solution to have to take though. It's strange that I haven't cleared my history in so many years of browsing.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't wish to delete your entire browser history, you can pick the annoying item in the omnibox and remove it with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> on Windows, or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> on MacOS.

Comment: To "save" the browsing history?  The exact action you're suggesting is unclear.

Comment: This answer is in contrast with the other answer. The other answer explains how to nuke all of your browser history. This answer explains how to delete just the one offending entry, thus "saving" the rest of your history, compared to the other approach.

Comment: This answer is amazing, thank you.